# Why is axios not displaying data in front end using useState, useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

get() working. When I got to the link and manually type `currAdmin = 1` It displays the data I need. Right now it wont display in my front end when I call it. This is what I have done so far. My Dashboard page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import UserContext from '../context/UserContext';
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./Header"
import { ListGroup, } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import LinkTime from './LinkTime';

function Dashboard() {
    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!userData.user)
            history.push("/");
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllLinks();
    }, []);

    const [mylinks, getLinks] = useState('');

    const getAllLinks = () => {
        let currAdmin = userData.user.adminId;
            axios.get('http://localhost:9000/Links/all?currAdmin=' + currAdmin)
            .then((response) => {
                const allLinks = response.data.mylinks.allLinks;
                getLinks(allLinks);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error'));
    }


    return (

        < LinkTime mylinks={mylinks} />
    );




}
```

This is my LinkTime file where I have my child function

```
import React from 'react'; 

export default function LinkTime(props) {
    console.log(props.mylink);

    const displayLinks = (props) => {
        const { mylinks } = props;

        if (mylinks.length > 0) {
            return (
                mylinks.map((mylink, index) => {
                    console.log(mylink);
                    return (
                        <div className='adminId' key={mylink._id}>
                            <p className="links"> {mylink.links} </p>
                             <h1 class="ID"> {mylink.adminId} </h1>
                        </div >
                    )
                })
            )

        } else {
           return <h2> no </h2>
        }
    }

    return (

        <>
            <h3> {displayLinks(props)} </h3>

        </>
    );
}
```

At the moment it only displays the else statement which is no. What am I doing wrong here that the data being called with axios isnt being received? On powershell it seems to grab the data. Any ideas would help!

Comment: if you look in your browser's Inspector's Network tab for the request when you load your page, what comes back in the response for `http://localhost:9000/Links/all?currAdmin=....'` ?

Comment: when the length is > 0 you're returning a div with nested p tag but there's no actual text inside it. where you able to see the logs inside the map `console.log(mylink);`?

Comment: @Yorkshireman This is what I get back if this is what you were asking about `GET /Links/all?currAdmin=1 304 472.809 ms - -` The 1 is for the value of one of the roles.

Comment: I think that's the Request you're showing me there - what's the Response?

Comment: @Yorkshireman sorry I'm new at this so I went ahead and looked under the response and it shows this `[{"_id":"5fc43233c814618b24b0ed34","links":"www.adminlink1.com","adminId":1,"createdAt":"2020-11-29T23:43:47.968Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-29T23:43:47.968Z","__v":0}]` Which is the data I want no clue why its not showing though.

Comment: @RameshReddy Oh wow sorry I just caught that. I believe its suppose to be like this `<p className="links"> {mylink.links} </p>` I tried it like so but it still not showing anything just drops to the else statement

Comment: you see where you have `console.log(props.mylink)` in `LinkTime`? Change that to `console.log(props.mylinks` (make sure you have the `s` on the end), and see what that logs out in your console when you load the page

Comment: @Yorkshireman Hm. Seems to just say undefined. with mylinks or mylink. They both say undefined

Comment: yeah I think the problem might be your `const allLinks = response.data.mylinks.allLinks;` Log out `response.data` and see what that gives you.

Comment: @Yorkshireman Yeah it doesn't seem to show anything actually

Comment: What does `console.log(response);` give you?

Comment: @Yorkshireman with that one undefined again

Comment: maybe you need `return` before `axios.get`

Comment: first job is to get `console.log(response)` actually logging something out

Comment: @Yorkshireman Do you happen to know why I am getting an error with the console itself? Looks something like this `!function(e,t){"object` its an extremely long line of code. I am not sure where it comes from though as I havent touched that

Comment: Are you sure your data can be accessed with `response.data.mylinks.allLinks`. The example response body you showed us, contains only a list which would be accessed with `response.data` only. Just a guess. I also do not understand why you use such a complicated program structure. Wouldn't it be better to use a sub component for single links. And the HTML at the end of the  LinkTime Function Component is a bit emmmm strange.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I may have over complicated things looking at different resources to figure this out. You were correct about response data thank you so much.

Comment: @Yorkshireman Thank you also the console errors also helped in solving this issue

Comment: You're welcome. But without Yorkshireman asking you for the output, I would not have the idea. So, he's the hero. Keep on learning, have success and may the force be with you. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Peter - @dmart14 have you got it working?

Comment: @Yorkshireman Yes I did its fully working now luckily thank you for the help!

Comment: good news have fun